# How to make the two very similar columns from two different trables show under the same primary key in the main table

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have two tables called VAL and VAL_SUB in my database. The primary key / driver table in this situation is a table called MAIN (as shown below)

```
MAIN_ID    MAIN_NAME    CREATED_DT    Units
  1         Height      DEC-14-18     INches
  2         Weight      DEC-12-18     LBs
```

I currently have a process/job in place that calculates values to substitute in for 'extreme', null or missing values in the VAL table. The VAL table will contain all of the original data that was parsed in (as shown below):

```
 VAL_ID     VAL      Hour          Date
   1        -87       01:00 AM      NOV-30-18
   2         8        02:00 AM      NOV-30-18
   3        18        03:00 AM      NOV-30-18
```

The VAL_SUB will contain any values that were updated/substituted using the above logic but also the values that were left 'untouched'.

```
  VAL_SUB_ID     VAL         Hour          Date
      1          12          01:00 AM      NOV-30-18
```

The VAL and VAL_SUB table will each have a separate RELationship table to the MAIN table (as shown below)

VAL_MAIN_REL

```
     VAL_MAIN_ID    VAL_ID         MAIN_ID
         1            1               2
         2            2               2 
         3            3               1
```

VAL_SUB_MAIN_REL

```
     VAL_SUB_MAIN_ID    VAL_SUB_ID      MAIN_ID
         1              1               2
```

I need a query that shows the 'subbed' and original values in one table/row (as shown below):

```
 MAIN_ID        ORIG_VAL       SUB_VAL       UNITS      HOUR        DATE
    1              18           null         Inches     03:00 AM    30-NOV-18
    2               8           null         LBS        02:00 AM    30-NOV-18
    2              -87           12          LBS        01:00 AM    30-NOV-18
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't produce the desired output (instead, it returns nulls for both the orig val and sub val columns) Do I need to do some sort of grouping?:

```
 select m.main_id
      , v.val    as ORIG_VAL
      , sv.val   as SUB_VAL
      , m.units
      , v.hour
      , v.date
    from main m
    join VAL_MAIN_REL VMR on m.main_id = vmr.main_id
    join VAL V on VMR.val_id = V.val_id
    join VAL_SUB_MAIN_REL VSMR on vsmr.main_id = m.main_id
    join VAL_SUB VS on VSMR.VAL_ID = vs.VAL_SUB_ID;
```

Comment: Your query has `vs.val_id` which doesn't seem to exist, and 'date' isn't a valid column name - why do you have date and time in separate columns anyway? And are those column relevant to what you're trying to do - or do they just happen to match for the 'sub' row? It would gave us consistent data and queries that run and do what you describe...

Comment: they have to match at Date / Time (so if a value for today at 1:00 pm was 'bad' , there would be replacement value in the second val table).

Comment: OK, so that's why -87 has a sub of 12, but 8 doesn't - because the date/times don't match?

Comment: Yes that is correct both the date, time, and units (which ultimately lead to what is being measured)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a left outer join, which is based on both the 'sub' relationship and the matching date/time from the two tables:

```
select m.main_id,
  v.val as orig_val,
  vs.val as sub_val,
  m.units,
  v.hour,
  v.date
from main m
join val_main_rel vmr on vmr.main_id = m.main_id
join val v on v.val_id = vmr.val_id
left join val_sub_main_rel vsmr on vsmr.main_id = m.main_id
left join val_sub vs on vs.val_sub_id = vsmr.val_sub_id
  and vs.date_ = v.date
  and vs.hour = v.hour;
```

Quick demo with CTEs for your sample data, with the 'date' column renamed as 'date_' so it's a valid identifier:

```
-- CTEs for sample data, with 'date_' instead of 'date'
with main (main_id, main_name, created_dt, units) as (
  select 1, 'Height', date '2018-12-14', 'INches' from dual
  union all select 2, 'Weight', date '2018-12-12', 'LBs' from dual
),
val (val_id, val, hour, date_) as (
  select 1, -87, '01:00 AM', date '2018-11-30' from dual
  union all select 2, 8, '02:00 AM', date '2018-11-30' from dual
  union all select 3, 18, '03:00 AM', date '2018-11-30' from dual
),
val_sub (val_sub_id, val, hour, date_) as (
  select 1, 12, '01:00 AM', date '2018-11-30' from dual
),
val_main_rel (val_main_id, val_id, main_id) as (
  select 1, 1, 2 from dual
  union all select 2, 2, 2 from dual
  union all select 3, 3, 1 from dual
),
val_sub_main_rel (val_sub_main_id, val_sub_id, main_id) as (
  select 1, 1, 2 from dual
)
-- actual query
select m.main_id,
  v.val as orig_val,
  vs.val as sub_val,
  m.units,
  v.hour,
  v.date_
from main m
join val_main_rel vmr on vmr.main_id = m.main_id
join val v on v.val_id = vmr.val_id
left join val_sub_main_rel vsmr on vsmr.main_id = m.main_id
left join val_sub vs on vs.val_sub_id = vsmr.val_sub_id
  and vs.date_ = v.date_
  and vs.hour = v.hour;
```

```
   MAIN_ID   ORIG_VAL    SUB_VAL UNITS  HOUR     DATE_     
---------- ---------- ---------- ------ -------- ----------
         2        -87         12 LBs    01:00 AM 2018-11-30
         2          8            LBs    02:00 AM 2018-11-30
         1         18            INches 03:00 AM 2018-11-30
```

---

The multiple outer joins and duplicated `main_id` entries you have in your actual `val_sub` table are conspiring to make unwanted matches, as you describe in a comment. There is a match to the `vsmr` relation table, but not then on to the `vs` table when date/hour are taken into account - but the first outer join matching is enough to produce extra unwanted rows in the output.

With a modified CTE to have a second sub value:

```
-- CTEs for sample data, with 'date_' instead of 'date'
with main (main_id, main_name, created_dt, units) as (
  select 1, 'Height', date '2018-12-14', 'INches' from dual
  union all select 2, 'Weight', date '2018-12-12', 'LBs' from dual
),
val (val_id, val, hour, date_) as (
  select 1, -87, '01:00 AM', date '2018-11-30' from dual
  union all select 2, 8, '02:00 AM', date '2018-11-30' from dual
  union all select 3, 18, '03:00 AM', date '2018-11-30' from dual
),
val_sub (val_sub_id, val, hour, date_) as (
  select 1, 12, '01:00 AM', date '2018-11-30' from dual
  -- extra row added below
  union all select 2, 13, '02:00 AM', date '2018-11-30' from dual
),
val_main_rel (val_main_id, val_id, main_id) as (
  select 1, 1, 2 from dual
  union all select 2, 2, 2 from dual
  union all select 3, 3, 1 from dual
),
val_sub_main_rel (val_sub_main_id, val_sub_id, main_id) as (
  select 1, 1, 2 from dual
  -- extra row added below
  union all select 2, 2, 2 from dual
)
...
```

the original query gets:

```
   MAIN_ID   ORIG_VAL    SUB_VAL UNITS  HOUR     DATE_     
---------- ---------- ---------- ------ -------- ----------
         2        -87         12 LBs    01:00 AM 2018-11-30
         2          8         13 LBs    02:00 AM 2018-11-30
         2          8            LBs    02:00 AM 2018-11-30
         1         18            INches 03:00 AM 2018-11-30
         2        -87            LBs    01:00 AM 2018-11-30
```

So I think you need to eliminate those via a subquery, so you can do a single outer join instead:

```
select m.main_id,
  v.val as orig_val,
  vsx.val as sub_val,
  m.units,
  v.hour,
  v.date_
from main m
join val_main_rel vmr on vmr.main_id = m.main_id
join val v on v.val_id = vmr.val_id
left join (
  select vsmr.main_id, vs.val, vs.date_, vs.hour
  from val_sub_main_rel vsmr
  join val_sub vs on vs.val_sub_id = vsmr.val_sub_id
) vsx on vsx.main_id = m.main_id
and vsx.date_ = v.date_
and vsx.hour = v.hour;
```

which gets the more-reasonable-looking output:

```
   MAIN_ID   ORIG_VAL    SUB_VAL UNITS  HOUR     DATE_     
---------- ---------- ---------- ------ -------- ----------
         2        -87         12 LBs    01:00 AM 2018-11-30
         2          8         13 LBs    02:00 AM 2018-11-30
         1         18            INches 03:00 AM 2018-11-30
```

Comment: Thank you. hmm for some reason I am getting the same value being populated in the orig_val column repeatedly for every value in sub_val (as if the query is doing some sort of combination)... wonder what's going on.

Comment: @JohnWick - yeah... I've updated with a modified version that will hopefully fix that for you.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I am still seeing bizarre results where sub_val is being populated even though no substitution ever took place...

Comment: I can't see anything else obviously wrong. I guess there could be duplicates in your data, but I imagine the IDs are PKs? Would probably need to see the relevant data, but then if you can figure out all the data you need to reproduce you, you'll probably be able to see the problem yourself anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Join one table at a time using left join

```
SELECT m.main_id, v.val as ORIG_VAL, sv.val as SUB_VAL, m.units, v.hour, v.date
FROM main m
LEFT JOIN VAL_MAIN_REL vm ON vm.main_id = m.main_id 
JOIN val v ON vm.val_id = v.val_id 
LEFT JOIN val_sub_main_rel sm ON sm.main_id = m.main_id 
JOIN val_sub sv ON sm.val_sub_id = sv.val_sub_id 
WHERE v.hour = sv.hour 
  AND v.date = sv.date
```

Comment: Would this show both values under the same main id?

Comment: @JohnWick Ah, no it wouldn't. I missed that part- Let me see if I can update my answer

Comment: for some reason when I implement this method to whats in my database I am returning a lot more entries than I should. looks like oracle is finding combinations of the two columns. (so for example I am returning several entries with SUB_VAL being 12 - if that makes sense).